# Get historical data for multiple stocks in single request using python from Google finance

Tags: python, google-finance, google-finance-api

I am able to get historical data on one stock per each request. But I need to get historical data for multiple stocks in a single request from Google finance using python.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't request time series data for multiple stocks from that source at once. Instead, you have to put your request into a loop. Putting your request into a loop, you can request time series stock by stock.

Comment: But it's refusing API calls if morethan 5 per second

Comment: Maybe Google has throttled the maximum API-requests per second. In this case, you have to limit your requests per minute inside your loop. If you make too many calls per second, then you are not a private user and then you have to buy the data.